# How to decide whether to make a separate class for widgets of a window?

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns

The main window contains a:

- TODO list (text box), time allotted (list box), start time (text box).
- Count down timer (timer), start button (button).

I already have a class for the timer which contains few slots too.

Remaining widgets have their objects declared in the main() currently.

Now, I need to get the clicked item from the list and supply it to the timer.
The way to do it is to create signal-slots.

How to decide whether to make a separate class for widgets of a window or club them all together?

Any design patterns here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any design patterns here?

A standard design pattern for GUI is [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter), [presenter first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presenter_First) or any variation. This means that the MVP classes should be as small as possible.

On the other hand, QT recommends to use [model/view](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/modelview.html).

> How to decide whether to make a separate class for widgets of a window or club them all together?

Try to form a logical entity - what you want your widget to do. If a timer is part of this entity, then put it there. Do not make [god classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), because if you do, you have misused the MVP pattern.